# App crashes on Cordova alert

Tags: android, cordova

On some Android devices, my Cordova-based app crashes around the time I prompt the user if they'd like to receive notifications, which happens on the first app startup. Here's a typical stack trace:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@<i>[eight hex digits]</i> is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:535)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
at org.apache.cordova.Notification$2.run(Notification.java:245)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The JavaScript code:

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
     'Do you wish to receive push notifications?',
     function(btnIndex) {
         if (btnIndex == 1) {
             push.enablePush();
             localStorage.pushAsked = true;
         } else {
             push.disablePush();
             localStorage.pushAsked = true;
         }
     },
     'Push Notifications',
     'Yes,No'
);
```

Any ideas? I don't know which devices or Android versions are affected, but that question is out there to those who have reported it.

I'm using Cordova 2.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are trying to display alert dialog while the activity is finishing.

You can subclass CordovaChromeClient and check for activity.isFinishing() on onJsAlert()

I have created a project on Github that solves this bug:
https://github.com/kruyvanna/CordovaAlertBug_Android

You can see an example below.

```
class CordovaOnJsAlertBug extends DroidGap{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

@Override
public void init() {
    Log.e(TAG, "init()");
    CordovaWebView webView = new CordovaWebView(CordovaOnJsAlertBug.this);
    CordovaWebViewClient webViewClient;
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        webViewClient = new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webView);
    }
    else
    {
        webViewClient = new IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(this, webView);
    }
    this.init(webView, webViewClient, new MyCordovaChromeClient(this, webView));
}

private class MyCordovaChromeClient extends CordovaChromeClient{
    private CordovaInterface cordova;
    public MyCordovaChromeClient(CordovaInterface ctx, CordovaWebView app) {
        super(ctx, app);
        this.cordova = ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        if(cordova.getActivity().isFinishing()){
            Log.w(TAG, "Trying to alert while activity is finishing!! -> ignore");
            result.cancel();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. One question: am I correct in assuming the subclass will prevent the dialog from appearing? If that's the case I'd need to work out a way around that, since I'd still need to prompt the user about push notifications.

Comment: Yes it will cancel the dialog. 

Can you include the code that cause this exception? It could help in understanding why your activity got destroyed.

Comment: I actually can't because it's proprietary code. But I have moved the push-notification prompt to native Java and eliminated at least that crash.