# Android Bad Token Exception when closing and opening fast

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, android-activity, token

I am currently working on an application that is being launched as an intent. Here are the flags I am using:

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);   // don't "zoom", etc. the launch
    intent.setFlags(PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This works great, however if you open and close it fast over and over I get this error:

```
04-15 17:47:05.190: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13515): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@408fe608 is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:530)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2170)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have done some research and understand that a lot of people have this issue. Most people get this error because they use a dialog with an application context. My application does not have any dialogs. I am using a this reference throughout my app. I have also placed some logs to determine where it is crashing. It happens after `onResume` is done.

Has anyone else had this issue?

I get this above that error.

```
04-15 17:47:05.190: WARN/WindowManager(2233): Attempted to add application window with unknown token HistoryRecord
```

Comment: possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959486/app-crashes-on-cordova-alert